# What exactly does CLActivityType.airborne do in the IOS CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, swift, gps, location, cllocationmanager

I am writing an IOS app where I need to track your location during a plane flight.  And I see in IOS 12, the CLLocationManager has a new option called "airborne":

```
locationManager.activityType = .airborne
```

While the apple documentation has a lot to say about many of the locationManager activity types, it says only this about airborne:

- The location manager is being used specifically during airborne activities.
- Use this activity type if the expected user activity is well above ground level.

But I would like to know what the airborne activity type actually controls.  Specifically, it would be nice if choosing "airborne" would switch off navigation by cell towers and only use GPS -- which would save significant power.  (Android allows me to control this directly.)

I have found zero information online, and I'm wondering if anybody out there has any insight about what "airborne" actually does?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It could be focusing on altitude.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocation/1423820-altitude

Comment: As far as I could determine, the "airborne" setting does nothing. 
BTW, the GPS is reasonably good at determining altitude -- probably within 10-20 meters.  It is certainly good enough for air travel.